# Proof Verification: General form of Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> > Prove that every linear map from $\Bbb{R^n}$ to $\Bbb{R^m}$ is in the form:
> >
> > $$T(x_1,...,x_n)=(a_{1,1}x_1+\dots +a_{1,n}x_n,\dots ,a_{m,1}x_1+\dots +a_{m,n}x_n)$$

I want to prove by using basic definition of linear maps only, i.e. $T(\vec u +\vec v)=T(\vec u)+T(\vec v)$ and $T(a\vec v)=aT(\vec v)$

Choose any basis of $\Bbb R^n$, say $(\vec v_1,\dots ,\vec v_n)$, and any basis $(\vec u_1, \dots, \vec u_m)$ from $\Bbb R^m$

Then by considering the vectors that the basis in $\Bbb R^n$ are being mapped to, they can be represented as linear combination of $\vec u_j$. I.e.

$$T(\vec v_i) = \sum_{k=1}^m a_{k,i} \vec u_k$$

So if we write any vector $\vec v\in \Bbb R^n$ as linear combination:

$$\vec v =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec v_i$$

Then $T(\vec v)$ is forced to give:

$$T\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec v_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i T\left(\vec v_i\right)= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i  \left(\sum_{k=1}^m a_{k,i} \vec u_k\right) $$

Rearranging the last expression gives:

$$T \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec v_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^m \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{k,i} x_i \right) \vec u_k$$

Representing $(x_1,...,x_n)$ as linear combination: $x_1 \vec v_1 + \dots +x_n \vec v_n$, and similarly for $\vec u_j$, this gives us the desired result:

$$T(x_1,...,x_n)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{1,i} x_i ), \dots, \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{n,i} x_i)\right)$$

I am not quite sure if my steps are valid or not as I am learning linear algebra on my own.

Comment: The one incorrect step here is "choose any basis".  In this setting, you should be using the standard bases for $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why so? I was trying to be general and show that it should be true regardless on the basis chosen. I take the expression $(x_1, \dots , x_n)$ to be equivalent to $x_1 \vec v_1 + \dots + x_n \vec v_n$ for the basis $\{ v_j \}_{j=1, \dots , n}$

Comment: If that's what you're doing, then you're using a non-standard definition of the expression $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.  There's nothing stopping from proving the more general statement (that a linear map can be expressed as a matrix with respect to an arbitrary choice of basis), but that is not the usual interpretation of what you've said.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see what you mean. Thanks for the help :)